# How do I get my program to stop once the "Q" button is pressed in AutoIt?

Tags: loops, for-loop, keyboard, autoit, terminate

I currently have a program set up in AutoIt. This is what's written as the code, as well as some notes that may be useful to answering my question:

```
;File with data is pw.txt
$fh = FileOpen("pw.txt")
;Loops 5 times, every time it loops $attempt should equal the next line of pw.txt
For $i = 1 To 10
$attempt = FileReadLine($fh)
MouseClick("left");MouseClick("left",711,256)
Sleep(700)
Send($attempt);Enters whatever is in $attempt variable
Sleep(700)
Send("{enter}")
Sleep(700)
MouseClick("left")
Sleep(700);Once first loop is finished, second loop begins. The only thing that is different is what is entered ($attempt)
Next
FileClose("pw.txt");After finished looping, file closes.
```

For the sake of this question, I set the loop count to 10, so after $i = 10 (after it loops 10 times), the program will still be active, but no actions will be carried out.

I want to make it so that if the user hits the "Q" button on the keyboard, my program stops, and does no further actions (I don't want to close the program entirely, just stop the loop). Preferably, I'd like the loop to start at 1 the next time I run the program

For example, if I was on loop 4 and I pressed the "Q" button, the loop would stop, and then I should be able to click the "F5" button to run my program again, and it would be on loop 1.

**Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!**

Comment: Look at HotKeySet

Answer (score 0):

You need a main loop, that allows to run your timed loop again and again. Also you need functions for run and stop your timed loop, called by hotkeys:

```
HotKeySet('q', '_stopLoop')
HotKeySet('{F5}', '_runLoop')
HotKeySet('^!e', '_exit')    ; (Ctrl+Alt+e)   required to stop the main loop
Global $iLoopCounter

; start your loop now
_runLoop()


; you need a main loop
While True
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func _exit()
    Exit
EndFunc

Func _MyLoop()
    While $iLoopCounter < 10
        $iLoopCounter += 1
        ; your loop code here

        ;==================================== for demonstration
        ConsoleWrite('$iLoopCounter: ' & $iLoopCounter & @CRLF)
        Sleep(1000)
        ;======================================================

    WEnd
EndFunc

Func _runLoop()
    $iLoopCounter = 0
    _MyLoop()
EndFunc

Func _stopLoop()
    $iLoopCounter = 10
EndFunc
```